# How do I have a copy of a variable in a React functional component that doesn't change?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

I have a variable `const foo: Array<ObjectExt> = useSelector(fooSelector);` in a functional component. I want a copy of this variable from the first time the component is loaded that does not change when `foo` does.

When working with class components, I could simply have `const fooCopy = foo.slice();` but that does not work here since the component reloads every time and `fooCopy` changes.

How do I achieve this in a functional component?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just `useState` with the initial value as a copy of `foo`.

```
const foo : Array<ObjectExt> = useSelector(fooSelector);
const [origFoo] = useState(foo.slice());
```

Once `origFoo` has been initialized, it won't be re-initialized on rerender. You can destructure the setter out if you need to update its value later:

```
const [origFoo, setOrigFoo] = useState(foo);
// ...
if(someCondition) setOrigFoo(foo.slice())
```

```js
const {useState} = React;

function App() {
  const foo = [new Date().getTime()];
  const [origFoo] = useState(foo.slice());

  // Just so we have a way to force a rerender
  const [count, setCount] = React.useState(0);

  return (
    <div>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(foo)} </p>
      <p>{JSON.stringify(origFoo)}</p>
      <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>Update</button>
    </div>
  );
}

const rootElement = document.getElementById("root");
ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  rootElement
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to set a flag in local component state. If that flag is fals, then make a copy of the value. Otherwise, don't.

Answer (score 0):

The solution I'd use to accomplish this functionality, is to make a copy of `foo`, something like `initialFoo` in the store, and pick it in needed components.

Answer (score 0):

> I want a copy of this variable from the first time the component is loaded that does not change when foo does.

When you use `useSelector(selector)` then react-redux will run `selector` every time the state changes, if the return value is different than then last time it ran then react-redux will re render the component.

The easiest way of doing this is using a selector that returns only the value it got when called the first time:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = { count: 0 };
//action types
const ADD = 'ADD';
//action creators
const add = () => ({
  type: ADD,
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === ADD) {
    return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectCount = (state) => state.count;
 //function returning a function
const createSelectInitialCount = () => {
  //initialize NONE when createSelectInitialCount is called
  const NONE = {};
  let last = NONE;
  //return the selector
  return (state) => {
    //check if last value was set
    if (last === NONE) {
      //set last value (only when called the first time)
      last = selectCount(state);
    }
    return last;
  };
};

//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
const InitialFoo = React.memo(function InitialFoo(props) {
  const selectInitialCount = React.useMemo(//can also use useCallback
    createSelectInitialCount,//createSelectInitialCount() if you use useCallback
    []
  );
  const foo = useSelector(selectInitialCount);
  return (
    <div>
      <h3>initialfoo</h3>
      <pre>
        {JSON.stringify({ ...props, foo }, undefined, 2)}
      </pre>
    </div>
  );
});

const App = () => {
  const foo = useSelector(selectCount);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [other, setOther] = React.useState(0);
  const [showFoo, setShowFoo] = React.useState(true);
  const remountFoo = () => {
    setShowFoo(false);
    Promise.resolve().then(() => setShowFoo(true));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(add())}>
        foo:{foo}
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setOther((o) => o + 1)}>
        other{other}
      </button>
      <button onClick={remountFoo}>remount Foo</button>
      {showFoo && <InitialFoo other={other} />}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```

Another way is to create a pure component using React.memo with a custom compare function that ignores foo:

```js
const { Provider, useDispatch, useSelector } = ReactRedux;
const { createStore, applyMiddleware, compose } = Redux;

const initialState = { count: 0 };
//action types
const ADD = 'ADD';
//action creators
const add = () => ({
  type: ADD,
});
const reducer = (state, { type, payload }) => {
  if (type === ADD) {
    return { ...state, count: state.count + 1 };
  }
  return state;
};
//selectors
const selectCount = (state) => state.count;
//creating store with redux dev tools
const composeEnhancers =
  window.__REDUX_DEVTOOLS_EXTENSION_COMPOSE__ || compose;
const store = createStore(
  reducer,
  initialState,
  composeEnhancers(
    applyMiddleware(() => (next) => (action) =>
      next(action)
    )
  )
);
const InitialFoo = React.memo(
  function InitialFoo(props) {
    return (
      <div>
        <h3>initialfoo</h3>
        <pre>{JSON.stringify(props, undefined, 2)}</pre>
      </div>
    );
  },
  //custom compare function when returning false
  //  component will re render
  ({ other }, { other: newOther }) => {
    return other === newOther;
  }
);
const InitialFooContainer = (props) => {
  const foo = useSelector(selectCount);
  //store foo in ref, will never change after mount
  const fooRef = React.useRef(foo);
  const newProps = { ...props, foo: fooRef.current };
  return <InitialFoo {...newProps} />;
};

const App = () => {
  const foo = useSelector(selectCount);
  const dispatch = useDispatch();
  const [other, setOther] = React.useState(0);
  const [showFoo, setShowFoo] = React.useState(true);
  const remountFoo = () => {
    setShowFoo(false);
    Promise.resolve().then(() => setShowFoo(true));
  };
  return (
    <div>
      <button onClick={() => dispatch(add())}>
        foo:{foo}
      </button>
      <button onClick={() => setOther((o) => o + 1)}>
        other{other}
      </button>
      <button onClick={remountFoo}>remount Foo</button>
      {showFoo && (
        <InitialFooContainer foo={foo} other={other} />
      )}
    </div>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.8.4/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.8.4/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/redux/4.0.5/redux.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-redux/7.2.0/react-redux.min.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```